# How can I determine which Windows DLL is being used for a function call?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, msvcrt, ntdll

I've been looking into `_vsnprintf` and have learnt that it is available in ntdll.dll and msvcrt.dll.

I can use `GetModuleHandle` and `GetProcAddress` to access `_vsnprintf`, for example:

```
static int(__cdecl *p__vsnprintf)(char *str, size_t count, const char *format, va_list valist);

static void init(const char *dll)
{
    HMODULE hmod = GetModuleHandleA(dll);
    if (hmod)
    {
        printf("*** Testing %s ***\n", dll);

        p__vsnprintf = (void *)GetProcAddress(hmod, "_vsnprintf");
        if (p__vsnprintf) test__vsnprintf();
        else printf("_vsnprintf not found in %s.\n", dll);
    }
    else printf("*** Unable to load %s ***\n", dll);

    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    init("ntdll.dll"); /* ntdll _vsnprintf */
    init("msvcrt.dll"); /* msvcrt _vsnprintf */

    printf("*** Testing normal function call ***\n");
    test_vsnprintf(); /* _vsnprintf in ??? */

    return 0;
}
```

For the generic call, how can I tell whether Windows is using `_vsnprintf` from ntdll.dll or msvcrt.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dumpbin /imports` will tell you.  Also, the handy [`depends` utility](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `dumpbin` program. The output showed that `_vsnprintf` was only being called from msvcrt.dll. I had to use it with VS2010. Is it available with VS2013?

Comment: If you mean is `dumpbin` available with VS2013, the answer is yes.  `dumpbin` is just a small wrapper program that invokes `link /dump`.

Answer (score 1):

To do it pragmatically you have a two main options options:

1. If its a static import, you can spelunk the IAT and inspect the module(s) its imported from.
2. If you are doing it dynamically (ie: Using `GetProcAddress`), you can use [`VirtualQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out the module its from. There is also [`GetModuleBaseName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683196(v=vs.85).aspx) for looking up a module name.
3. Just keep track of the `HMODULE` used when you have a successful `GetProcAddress` in you example above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check out the WinAPI functions you listed. With point 3, is that a suggestion for the code example I used? I'm not sure what you mean by keeping track of the `HMODULE`.

Comment: @HughMcMaster: Yes it was a suggestion for the example code. Basically you have an additional global variable along with the function pointer that holds either the module name or handle of the module used to (successfully) get the function pointer.